# NetworkManager to use dhclient to reserve and set IP for wlan intf

Tags: linux, networkmanager, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I want to reserve and get assigned an pre-defined IP address for `wlan0` interface on my client.

I have set:

`# cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf`:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

`# cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

#send dhcp-client-identifier 192.168.0.108;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/sbin/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "wlan0";
#  fixed-address 192.168.0.108;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "banan.dev";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.168.0.1;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}

host bananapim2zero {
    hardware ethernet ac:6a:a3:27:8a:e1;
    fixed-address 192.168.0.108;
}
```

`# systemctl status NetworkManager.service`

```
 NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-04-19 20:45:08 CEST; 6min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1103 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 888)
     Memory: 11.5M
        CPU: 1.274s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             ├─1103 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
             └─1303 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-56269e02-ee63-423f-bc6c-97067633aa9a-wlan0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf wlan0

Apr 19 20:45:17 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929917.5831] policy: set 'jebnato' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.2894] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.2982] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.3126] manager: startup complete
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.3193] device (wlan0): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::1ea1:1ea:1b97:6dbd/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 11-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute,tentative,0x8 s>
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.3196] device (wlan0): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::f49e:9be3:cea2:c5c4/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 11-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute,tentative,0x8 >
Apr 19 20:45:18 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929918.6471] device (wlan0): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::1ea1:1ea:1b97:6dbd/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 11-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute,tentative,0x8 s>
Apr 19 20:45:19 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929919.0517] device (wlan0): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::f49e:9be3:cea2:c5c4/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 12-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute,tentative,0x8 >
Apr 19 20:45:19 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1681929919.2169] device (wlan0): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::2b24:4b8f:cfa4:39fe/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 12-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags permanent,noprefixroute,tentative,0x8 >
Apr 19 20:45:19 bananapim2zero NetworkManager[1103]: <warn>  [1681929919.2172] device (wlan0): linklocal6: failed to generate an address: Too many DAD collisions
```

`/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf`:

```
# Created by NetworkManager
# Merged from /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
#send dhcp-client-identifier 192.168.0.108;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/sbin/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;
#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}
#lease {
#  interface "wlan0";
#  fixed-address 192.168.0.108;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "banan.dev";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.168.0.1;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
host bananapim2zero {
hardware ethernet ac:6a:a3:27:8a:e1;
fixed-address 192.168.0.108;
}
send host-name "bananapim2zero"; # added by NetworkManager

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option wpad code 252 = string;

request; # override dhclient defaults
also request subnet-mask;
also request broadcast-address;
also request time-offset;
also request routers;
also request domain-name;
also request domain-name-servers;
also request domain-search;
also request host-name;
also request dhcp6.name-servers;
also request dhcp6.domain-search;
also request dhcp6.fqdn;
also request dhcp6.sntp-servers;
also request netbios-name-servers;
also request netbios-scope;
also request interface-mtu;
also request rfc3442-classless-static-routes;
also request ntp-servers;
also request ms-classless-static-routes;
also request static-routes;
also request wpad;
also request root-path;
```

that means `NetworkManager` should use `dhclient` as it's DHCP backend and I have added to it's configuration the section (probably wrong one) to fix (but I want reserve so it won't fail if not available) the address. not working; badly documented.

OS: armbian latest

thanks in advance